# Scrape Yelp using NodeJS and web scraping APIs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, yelp

I'm trying to scrape data from Yelp by following the [instructions](https://scrape-it.cloud/blog/how-to-scrape-yelp-using-nodejs#programming). But after starting scraping, nothing happens in my console. The terminal processes the request for a while, and then returns nothing. What am I doing wrong? The code is completely taken from the manual.

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qQDT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid. I made a mistake in the code from the section https://scrape-it.cloud/blog/how-to-scrape-yelp-using-nodejs#:~:text=Implementing%20YelpParser%20class%20methods. Everything works well, the data is extracted:)